# JPA/Primefaces - Adicionar/Remover registros de uma tabela filha

Tags: java, primefaces, hibernate, jpa, datatable

Eu estou com um problema em um painel cadastral.

Existe um cadastro de rede de lojas em que estou cuidando da implementação. Consigo inserir e remover normalmente os itens do dataTable, mas isto não é refletido na base no processo de gravação - quando insiro ou removo um item da lista de filiais, o processo de gravação simplesmente ignora. Eu não consigo encontrar o que acontece.

```
<p:dataTable rowIndexVar="idx" id="grdPj" var="pj"  
                            scrollable="true"
                            scrollHeight="275"
                            value="#{cadRedeMBean.rede.pessoaJuridicas}"
                            emptyMessage="" 
                            widgetVar="grid">                               
                            <p:column headerText="Cód." width="15%" >
                                <h:outputText value="#{pj.cdPessoaJuridica}"></h:outputText>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="CNPJ" width="25%" >
                                <h:outputText value="#{pj.cdCnpj}"></h:outputText>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Nome Fantasia" width="50%" >
                                <h:outputText value="#{pj.nmFantasia}"></h:outputText>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Remover" width="10%" >
                                <p:commandButton icon="ui ui-icon-minusthick" title="Remover loja da rede" action="#{cadRedeMBean.delFilial}" update="grdPj">
                                    <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                        target="#{cadRedeMBean.filial}" value="#{pj}"></f:setPropertyActionListener>
                                </p:commandButton>
                            </p:column>                             
                        </p:dataTable>
```

Aqui o xhtml, onde tem o botão que chama o método de exclusão, que é este abaixo, que acompanha o método para adicionar.

```
    public void addFilial(){
    if (filial instanceof PessoaJuridica){
        rede.addPessoaJuridica(filial);
    }
}

public void delFilial(){
    if (filial instanceof PessoaJuridica){
        rede.removePessoaJuridica(filial);          
    }
}
```

O método para atualizar a rede acompanha um merge (ou um persist, em caso de inserção) no objeto rede.

**Atualizando - os Models**

*Rede*

```
@Entity
@Table(name="REDE")
@NamedQuery(name="Rede.findAll", query="SELECT r FROM Rede r")
public class Rede implements Serializable {
    /*Aqui tem Hashcodes e Equals*/
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private long cdRede;
    private String nmRede;
    private List<PessoaJuridica> pessoaJuridicas;
    private PessoaJuridica pessoaJuridica;

    public Rede() {
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SQ_CD_REDE" )
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SQ_CD_REDE", sequenceName = "SQ_CD_REDE", allocationSize = 1)    
    @Column(name="CD_REDE")
    public long getCdRede() {
        return this.cdRede;
    }

    public void setCdRede(long cdRede) {
        this.cdRede = cdRede;
    }


    @Column(name="NM_REDE")
    public String getNmRede() {
        return this.nmRede;
    }

    public void setNmRede(String nmRede) {
        this.nmRede = nmRede;
    }


    //bi-directional many-to-one association to PessoaJuridica
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="rede", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    public List<PessoaJuridica> getPessoaJuridicas() {
        return this.pessoaJuridicas;
    }

    public void setPessoaJuridicas(List<PessoaJuridica> pessoaJuridicas) {
        this.pessoaJuridicas = pessoaJuridicas;
    }

    public PessoaJuridica addPessoaJuridica(PessoaJuridica pessoaJuridica) {
        getPessoaJuridicas().add(pessoaJuridica);
        pessoaJuridica.setRede(this);

        return pessoaJuridica;
    }

    public PessoaJuridica removePessoaJuridica(PessoaJuridica pessoaJuridica) {
        getPessoaJuridicas().remove(pessoaJuridica);
        pessoaJuridica.setRede(null);

        return pessoaJuridica;
    }


    //bi-directional many-to-one association to PessoaJuridica
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CD_PESSOA_JURIDICA")
    public PessoaJuridica getPessoaJuridica() {
        return this.pessoaJuridica;
    }

    public void setPessoaJuridica(PessoaJuridica pessoaJuridica) {
        this.pessoaJuridica = pessoaJuridica;
    }

}
```

PessoaJuridica

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PESSOA_JURIDICA")
@NamedQuery(name="PessoaJuridica.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM PessoaJuridica p")
public class PessoaJuridica implements Serializable,Cloneable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SQ_CD_PESSOA_JURIDICA" )
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SQ_CD_PESSOA_JURIDICA", sequenceName = "SQ_CD_PESSOA_JURIDICA", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name="CD_PESSOA_JURIDICA")
    private long cdPessoaJuridica;

    /**Demais colunas**/


    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Rede
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CD_REDE_LOJAS")
    private Rede rede;


    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Rede
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="pessoaJuridica", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Rede> redes;

    /**Getters & Setters**/
}
```

**Atualizando**
A chamada para gravar no MBean

```
public void gravarRede() {
        RedeImpl qryRede = new RedeImpl();
        if (rede.getPessoaJuridica() instanceof PessoaJuridica){
            if (rede.getPessoaJuridicas() instanceof List){
                if (rede.getPessoaJuridicas().size()==0){
                    rede.setPessoaJuridicas(null);
                }
            }
            if (rede.getPessoaJuridica().getCdPessoaJuridica()==0){
                rede.setPessoaJuridica(null);
            }
            boolean novo = (rede.getCdRede()==0);
            qryRede.novoRede(rede);
            Long idNovo = rede.getCdRede();
            if (novo){
                new Fncts().aviso("Código "+idNovo);
            }else{
                new Fncts().aviso("Atualização realizada!");                
            }
        }       
    }
```

E o **novoRede**

```
public void novoRede(Rede rede){ 
      try{
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        if (rede.getCdRede()>0){
            em.merge(rede);
        }else{
            em.persist(rede);
        }
        em.getTransaction().commit();
      }catch(Exception ex){
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
        System.out.println("---ERRO!----"+ex.getMessage());
      }
```

Comment: Não está muito claro o você quer dizer com "o processo de gravação simplesmente ignora". Ao clicar no botão de remoção o método não é chamado? O item não é removido do banco de dados?

Comment: @DiegoM Perdão, ontem na pressa acabei não conseguindo detalhar com precisão. Ao clicar no botão de remoção, o método `delfilial` é chamado e responde normalmente - o item é eliminado do `<p:dataTable>` porém, ao salvar, ele não elimina a referência de filial da base.

Comment: embora não seja muito recomendado, tente executar `entityManager.flush()` após o merge. Se não funcionar suspeito que possa ser um problema de mapeamento. Seria bom [edit] a pergunta para conter o código das entidades.

Comment: Você debugou o código para verificar se de fato a linha `rede.removePessoaJuridica(filial);` está sendo executada?

Comment: Outra coisa, `getPessoaJuridicas().remove(pessoaJuridica);` esta chamada está removendo o objeto da lista! Onde está a chamada para a remoção do objeto no banco ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos, o merge não replica todas as atualizações realizadas no objeto pai, incluindo as remoções dos registros filhos?

Comment: Não tenho certeza, @ThiagoPaiva. Mas mesmo assim, onde está ocorrendo o merge? Em qual ponto do código?

Comment: @JorgeCampos atualizei. Inclusive estou verificando se não é algo relacionado ao CascadeType nas anotações OneToMany no model, mas não obtive sucesso até o momento.

Comment: Ok, agora o que falta é, em que momento você chama o `gravarRede`? Sua pergunta original é que as alterações não estão sendo salvas no banco, a tabela atualiza (porque você removeu o objeto da lista) mas não salva no banco. Em nenhuma parte do código que você mostrou, tem uma chamada para o `gravarRede` , então, se você precisa que que salve no banco no momento do delete, deveria ser algo assim: ` if (filial instanceof PessoaJuridica){ rede.removePessoaJuridica(filial); rede.gravarRede(); } `

Comment: O `gravarRede` é chamado ao clicar no botão de salvar, que está no formulário. A ideia do processo é poder remover e adicionar as filiais e no momento da atualização da rede efetuar as inclusões e exclusões das filiais.

Se eu fizer desta forma ele gravaria na base as exclusões antes do momento planejado.

Comment: Então nada vai ser persistido no banco até você clicar no botão salvar. O remove que chama o delFilial vai remover os registros apenas do Datatable. Se o seu problema for no botão salvar, coloca o trecho de código que chama ele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema esta relacionado ao cascade ações, por exemplo: 
para factory hibernate (sessionfactory)

```
@Cascade(value = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                   CascadeType.DELETE, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
```

Se estiver usando factory JPA, tem umas versões que tem um bug, não funciona direito esse (factory JPA(entitymanager-factory)) mapeamento JPA. se não tiver restrições(requisitos de projeto) use o código acima.

```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="pessoaJuridica", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

Outra coisa seu objeto filho, tem que fazer sentido conforme sua ação executado no cascade, sofrida pelo pai, cuidar para não gerar um ciclo, pai salva filho, filho salva o pai e entram em um loop infinito.

Assim -> **Save** PAI -> filho tem **cascade Save** e por a vai, conforme sua ação desejada, sofrido pela raiz, vai ou não propagar para os galhos até chegar a folhas.

Detalhe para remove objetos, por lista, é obrigatório implementar os metodos hashCode e equals porque sem isso implementado de forma correta não funciona, isso não é hibernate é java.